# Can Salesforce Commerce Cloud used as IDP to External Application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

My requirement is to setup SSO between Salesforce Commerce Cloud B2C and BlackBoard/BrightSPace. Which means Salesforce Commerce Cloud will be IDP.

So when I try to login to BlackBoard/BrightSPace then if should redirected to CommerceCloud for login Authentication.

Please let me know how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to achieve, check SAML architecture, you should construct custom endpoints on CC side for that, also use private and public keys / certificates (public key will come from external cloud)